# Delete row if it contains duplicate value within the same row

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list that looks like this

```
a = [[1080, 1080, 1080, 1080], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1080, 1080, 1080, 1080],[1080, 0, 1080, 0],[0, 1080, 23, 1080], [1458, 975, 1579, 1077], [1458, 975, 1579, 1077]]
```

Ideally, it should like this

```
a=[[1458, 975, 1579, 1077], [1458, 975, 1579, 1077]]
```

All duplicates within the same row only gets deleted, or if x[0] equals x[2], or if x[1] equals x[3]. Being it numpy or list does not matter.

Here is my attempt

```
a = [[1080, 1080, 1080, 1080], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1080, 1080, 1080, 1080],[1080, 0, 1080, 0],[0, 1080, 23, 1080], [1458, 975, 1579, 1077], [1458, 975, 1579, 1077]]
new_cleaned_list = []
for x in a:
    if x[0] == x[1] and x[0] == x[2] and x[0] == x[3] or x[0] == x[2] or x[1] == x[3]:
        pass
    else:
        new_cleaned_list.append(x)
```

The application is removing non-zero co-ordinates in an image.

Comment: *duplicated * meaning **all** are the same or just **some** are the same?

Comment: @QuangHoang I updated the question. All values are duplicate, or first and third or second and fourth.

Comment: Your code seems to work. There's no need to check whether all values are dupes since that's a strict subset of `x[0] == x[2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @ggorlen, you don't need to check for duplicated. In which case, you can use slicing:

```
a = np.array(a)

mask = (a[:,0] != a[:,2]) & (a[:,1] !=a[:,3])
# or equivalently
# mask = (a[:,:2] != a[:,2:]).all(1);


out = a[mask]
```

---

```
array([[1458,  975, 1579, 1077],
       [1458,  975, 1579, 1077]])
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions, assuming that *a* is a *Numpy* array:

```
a[~np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: (row[0] == row[2]) or (row[1] == row[3]), 1, a)]
```